# Vendored Go dependencies fail to import

Tags: go, import, vendor

A tale of two projects:

I wrote go-ios7crypt as a quick way to learn Go packaging. The dependencies are vendored using git submodules, and installation is as easy as `go get github.com/mcandre/go-ios7crypt/...`

Source: https://github.com/mcandre/go-ios7crypt

However, I tried to repeat this pattern for another project, a DuckDuckGo command line launcher. I'm curious what I've done wrong, as neither `go get` nor `go build` work when applying the same git submodule-based vendoring to the dependencies for ddg.

Trace:

```
> go get github.com/mcandre/mcandre/go/ddg/...
```

(This silently fails to build the ddg binary.)

```
> where.exe ddg
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Also, the project fails to build from local sources:

```
> go build
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/skratchdot/open-golang/open" in any of:
        C:\tools\go1.7\src\github.com\skratchdot\open-golang\open (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\andrew\go\src\github.com\skratchdot\open-golang\open (from $GOPATH)

> echo $env:GOPATH
C:\Users\andrew\go
```

Source: https://github.com/mcandre/mcandre/tree/master/go/ddg

Could the problem be that ddg is a nested project? For comparison, github.com/mcandre/blah/blah/blah is a collection of Go and non-Go projects, whereas github.com/mcandre/go-ios7crypt is a single Go project.

For what it's worth, I'm using Go 1.7 via gvm 1.0.0, with git 2.8.4, in PowerShell, on Windows 10 Professional x86_64.

Comment: does the .gitmodule file changes the behavior of git relative to go get ? maybe you need to add that file too ?

Comment: Note: `go get` never checks out or updates code stored in vendor directories.   do you have this path: `%GOPATH%\src\github.com\mcandre\mcandre\go\ddg\vendor\github‌​.com\skratchdot\open‌​-golang\open` Or this one: `%GOPATH%\src\github.com\skratchdot\open-golang\open`